# Is it possible to play second hand Destiny 2 online?

Tags: destiny-2

I am considering to buy a second hand copy of Destiny 2 on PS4, not sure if I can play it online as the previous owner has registered this game under his account?

Thanks

Comment: Do be aware that if you buy Destiny 2 you will need to buy the DLC on top of that, unless you purchase a Forsaken edition.

Comment: @DavidYell Why the word "need"? Can't the game be played (but restricted) without the DLC? (Note that this is a genuine question, not a point to an eventual flaw, since I do not own any copy of the game.)

Comment: Of course it can, but you'll be locked out of content. I would imagine at this stage most people would buy a Forsaken edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Physical disks cannot be tied to an account, this goes for all games. There is also no registration process to worry about, your progress is saved to your PSN.